# JsonReaderException at parse() - HololensDeploy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I get an exception when deploying on a hololens. I don't know why or how to solve it. It happens in the following class.

```
class JsonConverter
{
    public Dictionary<GameObject, String> convertJsonToObject(String json) {
        Dictionary<GameObject, String> objectList = new Dictionary<GameObject, string>(); 

        //Change JSON String to JSON Object
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        //Open features array in the object
        foreach(JObject pipe in jObject["features"].ToArray())
        {
            //Parse JSON Object to Creator
            PipeLineCreator p = pipe.ToObject<PipeLineCreator>();
            objectList.Add(p.CreatePipes(),p.Type);
        }
        return objectList;
    }    
}
```

It either can't parse the data I receive or I don't get any data at all. For the lather I think the problem would lay in the following class.

```
class JsonReader
{    
    public String data { get; set; }
    public bool loaded { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator ReadData(String source) {
        using (WWW webClient = new WWW(source))
        {
            loaded = false;
            yield return webClient;
            data =  webClient.text;
            loaded = true;
        }
    }   
}
```

It tries to receive data from a remote web service, which returns Json. The program waits until the call is finished before continuing.

```
//reader is an instance of JsonReader
StartCoroutine(reader.ReadData(Globals.Globals.DATAURL));
yield return new WaitUntil(() => reader.loaded);
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question.

The problem for me was that I didn't receive any data from my WWW call.
Apparently the WWW class is used to receive HTML files but nothing else (or at least on the hololens).

Instead I used the UnityWebRequest class, which allows you to receive bytes from a call as follows.

```
public IEnumerator ReadData(String source) {
        using (UnityWebRequest webClient = UnityWebRequest.Get(source))
        {
            loaded = false;
            yield return webClient.SendWebRequest();
            byte[] bytes = webClient.downloadHandler.data;
            data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            loaded = true;
            if (data == null||data.Equals(""))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Data", "No Data recieved from service");
            }
        }

    }
```

To get the Json data from a byte array, you just have to Encode it with a UTF-8 encoder.

I hope this helps someone else as well.